# Avoid else statement running multiple times in a FOR loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I have this array, how can I avoid the else statement to happen as many times as much items there are in the array

```
             SoftwareBadges =
            [
{ Title: "Playtech", Guid: "7e9", xPos: "96" },
{ Title: "BetSoft", Guid: "890", xPos: "169" },
{ Title: "WagerWorks", Guid: "35c", xPos: "242" },
{ Title: "Rival", Guid: "c35", xPos: "314" },
{ Title: "NetEnt", Guid: "59e", xPos: "387" },
{ Title: "MicroGaming", Guid: "19a", xPos: "460" },
{ Title: "Cayetano", Guid: "155", xPos: "533" },
{ Title: "OpenBet", Guid: "cfe", xPos: "607" },
{ Title: "RTG", Guid: "4e6", xPos: "680" },
{ Title: "Cryptologic", Guid: "05d", xPos: "753" },
{ Title: "CTXM", Guid: "51d", xPos: "827" },
{ Title: "Sheriff", Guid: "63e", xPos: "898" },
{ Title: "Vegas Tech", Guid: "a50", xPos: "975" },
{ Title: "Top Game", Guid: "0d0", xPos: "1048" },
{ Title: "Party Gaming", Guid: "46d", xPos: "1121" }
            ];

            for (var s in SoftwareBadges) {
                if (SoftwareBadges[s]["Guid"] == "7e9"){
                   alert(SoftwareBadges[s]["Title"]);
                }
            else{alert('fdsfsdf');}
            }
```

Comment: What are you asking? How to make the else statement run once? or how to make the else statement run as many times as there are items in the array?

Comment: First, don't use `for-in` on arrays. Second, I don't see how the else would run every time, if that's what you're saying. There's one iteration where it won't run.

Comment: What do you want to happen when a badge with a non-matching Guid is found? Do you want it to stop checking the rest of the list, or do you want it to keep checking for more matching Guids, but only alert `fdsfsdf` once?

Comment: you want to check each item, there is no choice but to visit each item in the list

Comment: Maybe you're actually wanting to find the object with the given ID. If so , use `var obj = SoftwareBatches.find(o => o.Guid == "7e9")`. Otherwise I don't know what the problem is. If you don't want the `else` to run, just remove it. It's not required.

Comment: I'd like the else statement to run only once, yes Patrick!

Comment: Andrew Rueckert, I only want either the If statement to run if its true, or the else statement to run if the if statement is not true, only want them to run once not more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Array.find(). It returns the first element that meets the conditions of the callback, and will stop iterating over the rest.

```js
SoftwareBadges =
            [
{ Title: "Playtech", Guid: "7e9", xPos: "96" },
{ Title: "BetSoft", Guid: "890", xPos: "169" },
{ Title: "WagerWorks", Guid: "35c", xPos: "242" },
{ Title: "Rival", Guid: "c35", xPos: "314" },
{ Title: "NetEnt", Guid: "59e", xPos: "387" },
{ Title: "MicroGaming", Guid: "19a", xPos: "460" },
{ Title: "Cayetano", Guid: "155", xPos: "533" },
{ Title: "OpenBet", Guid: "cfe", xPos: "607" },
{ Title: "RTG", Guid: "4e6", xPos: "680" },
{ Title: "Cryptologic", Guid: "05d", xPos: "753" },
{ Title: "CTXM", Guid: "51d", xPos: "827" },
{ Title: "Sheriff", Guid: "63e", xPos: "898" },
{ Title: "Vegas Tech", Guid: "a50", xPos: "975" },
{ Title: "Top Game", Guid: "0d0", xPos: "1048" },
{ Title: "Party Gaming", Guid: "46d", xPos: "1121" }
            ];
            
let foundBadge = SoftwareBadges.find(badge => badge.Guid === '7e9');

console.log(foundBadge ? foundBadge : 'asdfads');
```

Comment: im working with Titanium which unfortunately doesnt support the newest JS otherwise it would be perfect

Comment: `Array.prototype.find` can be polyfilled: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=example

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want to send the alert only one time, is that it? To do this you need another variable, something like:

```
SoftwareBadges =
[
{ Title: "Playtech", Guid: "7e9", xPos: "96" },
{ Title: "BetSoft", Guid: "890", xPos: "169" },
{ Title: "WagerWorks", Guid: "35c", xPos: "242" },
{ Title: "Rival", Guid: "c35", xPos: "314" },
{ Title: "NetEnt", Guid: "59e", xPos: "387" },
{ Title: "MicroGaming", Guid: "19a", xPos: "460" },
{ Title: "Cayetano", Guid: "155", xPos: "533" },
{ Title: "OpenBet", Guid: "cfe", xPos: "607" },
{ Title: "RTG", Guid: "4e6", xPos: "680" },
{ Title: "Cryptologic", Guid: "05d", xPos: "753" },
{ Title: "CTXM", Guid: "51d", xPos: "827" },
{ Title: "Sheriff", Guid: "63e", xPos: "898" },
{ Title: "Vegas Tech", Guid: "a50", xPos: "975" },
{ Title: "Top Game", Guid: "0d0", xPos: "1048" },
{ Title: "Party Gaming", Guid: "46d", xPos: "1121" }
];

var enteredInElse = false;

for (var s in SoftwareBadges) {
    if (SoftwareBadges[s]["Guid"] == "7e9"){
        alert(SoftwareBadges[s]["Title"]);
    } else{ enteredInElse = true }
}
if(enteredInElse){
    alert('fdsfsdf');
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'd only want the else statement to run once,

Comment: this way if the array has the object, it will still run both the If statement in the ForLoop AND the ELSE statement,
I'd only want the if statement to run only if the conditions are fulfilled in the forloop.if, and only to have the else statement run once if the conditions are not fulfilled in the forloop.if

Comment: No matter what I do, it runs both the the IF and The Else statements if the statement is true